# android - parse byte[] from json using jackson/gson

Tags: android, json, parsing

Can anybody help me with parsing a byte[] from a json file -

JSON File looks like this:

```
    {
    name:"test"
    myImage:[67,78,....]
    }
```

I do not want to create a new JSONObject() and parse, because this file can have multiple images and system runs out of memory.

I want to use GSON/Jackson/JSONReader(android>3.1), but it mostly seems to have getInt(), getString() objects.

How can i parse the byte[] itself into an object which i can later convert to a drawable.

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Btw, under android 3.0, you can use GSON https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried? In Jackson, you could use a POJO like:

```
class Stuff {
  public String name;
  public byte[] myImage;
}

Stuff stuff = new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File("stuff.json"), Stuff.class);
```

which should work.

But this  JSON serialization is not the typical way to do it: it is more common to include byte array as base64 encoded data. This is how Jackson will serialize it as, if you use `ObjectMapper.writeValue(...)`. The reason is that base64 encoding will be more compact, use less memory than number arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it this way

```
InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(instream);
            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(jsonReader);
                jsonReader.beginArray();
                while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                    MyCustomObject cobj = gson.fromJson(jReader,
                            MyCustomObject.class);
                    byte[] image = cobj.Image;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject-> `getString().getBytes();`

GSON/JsonReader-> `getString().getBytes();`